# Echofon Twitter client: Can I do unread syncing between multiple Macs instead of just between a Mac and an iPhone/iPad?

Tags: mac, sync, twitter

I use Echofon for Twitter on my two Macs and I would like to sync the status of my read tweets between these two. I know I can [sync between a Mac and an iPhone/iPad](http://www.echofon.com/push-sync-guide.html), but can I also sync between two Macs?

I enabled syncing in the preferences on both Macs, but it doesn't seem to do sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been having this problem too.

From my limited testing, it looks like if Mac B is sleeping, when you wake it up it will be synced with Mac A. If both Macs are awake, neither will sync.

My solution right now is to put my work computer to sleep before I leave, and it's been synced with my home computer every morning when I wake it up.

Since my home computer runs background processes I don't want to put it to sleep during the day. I'm going to try to remember to close Echofon every day before I go to work so that it will hopefully get synced, too.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be correct. I can confirm that when one Mac sleeps or has Echofon closed, it will sync with the other. I had both Macs running at the same time and neither synced, just like you said.